Impact of Physics StackExchange usage on your career
Can having a quality profile on this site impact your career in a meaningful way?
I am not referring to the knowledge obtained from it. I am referring to the profile per se,for cv purposes.
Does anyone have experiences to share in this regard?

I’m voting to close this question because it's not really about physics per se.  It would be a perfect fit for [Academia.SE], though (perhaps more broadly phrased to include other stacks as well.)

From Chemistry, but related - https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4873/

Related, on the meta site: Is Physics SE on your CV?
